# Redirect 404 Page using Kohana Framework

Tags: kohana-3.2

How to redirecting page to homepage use Kohana 3.2

I try use .htaccess file but failed:

```
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/
ErrorDocument 400 http://www.domain.com/
ErrorDocument 401 http://www.domain.com/
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.domain.com/
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.domain.com/
```

Anyone help, please

Answer (score 0):

This is the Apache "404" Page. Which would only come if there is no "index.php"-file, which should not happen at all in Kohana.

You can read about error handling in the guide http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/errors .

Or for version 3.2 http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/errors (which is down at the moment).

Following the 3.3 documentation this should work

```
class HTTP_Exception_404 extends Kohana_HTTP_Exception_404 
{

    public function get_response()
    {
        HTTP::redirect('/');
    }      
}
```